# FTP Transactions Using Microsoft Visual C++ 6

Tags: c, visual-c++, file-io, ftp, visual-c++-6

Is there any tutorial about FTP transactions(like download, upload and files/directory listings) using Microsoft Visual C++ 6 using C language instead of C++?

Comment: Any reason it (a) has to be C, and (b) has to be in such an old compiler?

Comment: (a) Because I'm better in C than C++. (b) Because I'm trying to do some programs using old softwares running on a old machine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically want a WinInet FTP client, which is the Win32 API for this kind of thing.  You can do all this in straight C.

There's a decent writeup here:

http://www.teksoftco.com/articles/ftp%20client.htm

but the gist is: you use InternetOpen/InternetConnect to get a connection, then use FtpOpenFile/FtpGetFile/FtpPutFile etc.  There are FtpFindFirstFile/NextFile to enumerate directories, and other methods for interrogating your current directory, deleting files, etc.